# WebView html content has whitespaces on the right

Tags: android, html, webview

When I scroll a page to the right, I see the additional whitespaces that make the page wider.

[image]

How can I fit the page to the WebView without removing whitespaces? Is it possible to achieve this in the WebView?

Comment: This should be handled via css by setting width to 100% instead of a fixed width in pixels

Answer (score 0):

Try setting something like this

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

for every button you have in your layout in the .xml file of your layout.
Or 
You can add your custom css for that